# PowerShell module not exposing commands properly

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

I have a strange issue since I re-scaffolded my PowerShell module.

The cfsdevops.psm1 is fairly simple with it simply auto-importing all .ps1 files in `/private` and `/public`.

```
#Get public and private function definition files.
$Public  = @( Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot\Public\*.ps1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue )
$Private = @( Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot\Private\*.ps1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue )

#Dot source the files
Foreach($import in @($Public + $Private))
{
    Try
    {
        . $import.fullname
    }
    Catch
    {
        Write-Error -Message "Failed to import function $($import.fullname): $_"
    }
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function $Public.Basename
```

Once I publish all the files to my module path directory and attempt to run of the commands I get an error indicating it's not a valid command:

```
PS C:\> get-podconfig
get-podconfig : The term 'get-podconfig' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-podconfig
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (get-podconfig:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

However when I then run "Get-Command -Module cfsdevops" it lists all available commands and the work just fine in that session.

```
PS C:\> Get-Command -Module cfsdevops

CommandType     Name                    Version    Source
-----------     ----                    -------    ------
Function        add-deploymanifest      4.1.0      cfsdevops
Function        add-podconfig           4.1.0      cfsdevops
Function        add-tenant              4.1.0      cfsdevops
Function        gen-podconfig           4.1.0      cfsdevops
Function        get-aobcredential       4.1.0      cfsdevops
Function        get-podconfig           4.1.0      cfsdevops
Function        get-servertraffic       4.1.0      cfsdevops
Function        new-deploymanifest      4.1.0      cfsdevops
Function        publish-octopus         4.1.0      cfsdevops
Function        publish-webconfig       4.1.0      cfsdevops
Function        set-aobcredential       4.1.0      cfsdevops
Function        set-octopusapikey       4.1.0      cfsdevops
```

Comment: is "gen-podconfig" a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Get-Command -Module cfsdevops` does not show `get-podconfig`, but `gen-podconfig`. The error message makes therefore totaly sense.

Check the Script file name and your PowerShell Module Manifest (psd1-File) for typos.

Comment: So curious enough, my example above I fat-fingered - actual functions did not come back. 
However, since then miraculously it works. No changes made.